# How to Convert LocalTime to UTC Time in production server?

Tags: java

I Can able to convert local time to UTC tIME in my localhost(in ECLIPSE).

for converting, given local time into UTC time I write below code

```
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.TimeZone;

public class TimeToUtc {

    public static void main(String args[]) throws ParseException {
     SimpleDateFormat f = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
        f.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
      
     
        DateFormat simpleDateFormat1=new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
          java.util.Date dutyDay = (java.util.Date) simpleDateFormat1.parse("12:41:00");
          System.out.println(dutyDay);
        
        System.out.println(f.format(dutyDay));
        String dd = f.format(new Date());
}
}
```

output:-

```
Thu Jan 01 12:41:00 IST 1970
07:11:00
```

The above code is working well and good in my eclipse. but when I am Executing this java file in server(production), it gives output as local time only.
in server the output is gives like

```
 Thu Jan 01 12:41:00 IST 1970
    12:41:00
```

but, what I want is like in server.

```
Thu Jan 01 12:41:00 IST 1970
    07:11:00
```

please help me to solve this issue.
Thanks.

Comment: You cannot convert a local time to UTC without knowing the date too, because the difference between local time and UTC depends on things like whether DST (Daylight Savings Time) is in effect. Without a date, the result may be flawed.

Comment: You said "production server", so when you say "local time", so you mean the time of the server, or the time where the user is located? Note that the time of the server may not be the same as the time where the server is *located*.

Comment: You should probably check which TZ is set on your production server. The time difference between your local and production could be timezone offset which gets applied.

Comment: You use Java 8+? Switch to the `java.time` API, and your pain goes away almost immediately.